# verilog why sign_out[3:0] <= -3'sb111*sign_in[3:0] RHS synthesis to 9*sign_in[3:0]?

Tags: verilog

Why `-3'sb111` synthesized to 9, instead of -(-1)?

```
module top(in, clk, rst, out);

input [34:0] in;
output [35-1:0] out;
input clk, rst;

reg signed [35-1:0] out;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
  if (!rst)
    out[3:0] <= 0;
  else
    out[3:0] <= -3'sb111*in[3:0]; // 4'b1001
end
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
  if (!rst)
    out[7:4] <= 0;
  else
    out[7:4] <= -3'b111*in[3:0];
end
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
  if (!rst)
    out[11:8] <= 0;
  else
    out[11:8] <= -3'b011*in[3:0];
end
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
  if (!rst)
    out[15:12] <= 0;
  else
    out[15:12] <= -3'sb011*in[3:0];
end
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
  if (!rst)
    out[19:16] <= 0;
  else
    out[19:16] <= -3'sd1*in[3:1];
end
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
  if (!rst)
    out[34:20] <= 0;
  else
    out[34:20] <= 0;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Can you tell me, what you want these numbers to be in the code, -3'sb111, -3'sb011 and -3'sd1?

Comment: @vipin please explain the number -3'sb111

Comment: -3'sb111 means -1*(signed binary of "111") = -1 * -1 = 1. Why do you think its synthesised to 9?

Comment: @vipin I verified with formality.

Comment: For me it's synthesising to 1. I used xilinx ise. May be this is a tool depended problem. I am not sure though.

Comment: @vipin did you synthesis the same Verilog module I posted? It's content-aware, i.e. +/-/*/* is context-determined operators, operands size maybe sign/zero extended, and operands signedness maybe changed. I found it in http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2006-SNUG-Boston_standard_gotchas_presentation.pdf . But I have not figured it out the exact steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your equation,

signed RHS = signed operand * unsigned operand;

So the LHS will be a unsigned multiplication because there is at least one unsigned number involved.

Now we can write,

-3'sb111 = -1 * 3'sb111
         = 1111 * 111 = 1101001 (taking only LSB 4 bits we get 9).

In the equation in your code we have,

4 bit RHS = signed operand * 4 bit unsigned operand.

So the context determined signed operand will become 4 bit in size. 
That's why we are using 1111 for multiplying by -1. Since the result is much bigger than 4 bits, we take only the lsb 4 bits.

Similarly,

-3'sb110*4'b0001 = 1010

-3'sb101*4'b0001 = 1011

-3'sb011*4'b0001 = 1101

I hope this makes sense.